# Alias for a combination of grep and find is needed

Tags: bash, grep, find, alias

Many times I need to search from a directory and below for a pattern in all files with a specific type. For example, I need to ask grep not to look into files other than *.h, *.cpp or *.c. But if I enter:

```
grep -r pattern .
```

it looks into all files. If I enter:

```
grep -r pattern *.c
```

it tries *.c files in the current folder (no file in my case) and files in *.c folders (no folder in my case). I want to ask it too look into all folders but only into file with the given type. I think grep is not enough to be used for this purpose. So, I get help from find too, like this:

```
grep pattern `find . -name '*c'`
```

First, let me know whether I'm right about getting help from find. Can grep be enough? Second, I prefer to write an alias for bash to be used like this:

```
mygrep pattern c
```

to be translated to the same command avoiding usage of ` and ' and be simpler. I tried:

```
alias mygrep="grep $1 `find . -name '*$2'`"
```

But it doesn't work and issues an error:

```
grep: c: No such file or directory
```

I tried to change it, but I couldn't succeed to a successful alias.

Any idea?

Comment: to search only specific file type, `grep -r --include='*.c' 'pattern'`.. there are other options as well like `--exclude` and `--exclude-dir` .. in any case, as answered, use function instead of alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be better done as a [function than an alias](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080), and using `-exec` instead of [passing the output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) of `find` to `grep`.  That output would be subject to word splitting and globbing, so could produce surprising results as is.  Instead try:

```
mygrep () {
    find . -name "*$2" -exec grep "$1" {} +
}
```

Comment: oh ok. and where should i put this function?

Comment: @hamidi you could put it in your `.bash_profile` or wherever you would have put the alias

Comment: You could add `-color=always` to the `grep` command (i.e., just before `"$1"`)